# limpiar un datepicker de vuetify a traves de un metodo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Hola a todos tengo un código con un datepicker de Vuetify y no puedo hacer que a traves de un metodo se  limpien  los datos, aca el código:

```
  <v-menu
              v-model="menu"
              ref="menu"
              :close-on-content-click="false"
              :nudge-right="40"
              :return-value.sync="dateSelect"
              lazy
              transition="scale-transition"
              offset-y
              full-width
              min-width="290px"
            >
              <v-combobox
                v-on="this.dateSelect.length > 2 ? max2DateSelect() : ''"
                v-model="dateSelect"
                class="black--text"
                slot="activator"
                label="Desde / Hasta"
                prepend-icon="event"
                multiple
                single-line
                hide-details
                readonly
                dark
                color="white"
              ></v-combobox>
              <v-date-picker
                v-model="dateSelect"
              
              >
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                
                >
                  OK
                 
                </v-btn>
              </v-date-picker>
            </v-menu>
```

en el script se declara asi:

export default {

data() {

```
return {


  dateSelect: []
```

}
y un metodo para que limpie esa caja de texto:

methods: {

clearFields() {

```
     this.dateSelect = [ new Date() ]

}
```

}

pero no le llego no limpia la caja de texto, alguna ayuda? de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo lo que yo entendí a tu pregunta, espero te sirva de algo.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <v-date-picker v-model="dateSelected"></v-date-picker>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="dateSelected"
        label="Fecha seleccionada"
        solo
        class="pt-5"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="clearFields"> Limpiar campos </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dateSelected: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clearFields() {
      this.dateSelected = null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Por si quieres probar te dejo el link de codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-xbxhg?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/295984)

Comment: @padaleiana esta bien. Ya corregí la respuesta